# Bash process substitution

Tags: bash

I can figure out why the following process substitution doesn't work:

```
kompare <( echo one two ) <( echo three four )
```

Kompare opens, but says that the input files are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kompare` probably needs a real file in order to read it more than once, but is not programmed to check whether the supplied arguments behave.

Comment: Does that technically mean it's a bug in `kompare`?

Comment: @AndrewWood: It depends on what its documentation states. http://www.caffeinated.me.uk/kompare/ seems to only mention "compare two text files", so it is rather a feature request.

Comment: It may be impossible (or at least less efficient) to produce the smallest possible diff if you restrict the program to making a single, unidirectional pass through each file. `zsh`, at least, provides the `=( cmd )` construct for process substitution when a real file is necessary.